# Securing NestJS API without user authentication

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, nestjs

I have deployed an Angular 8 application and a Nest JS application using Heroku. Both deployments use https.

There is no authentication in the Angular application, so I don't need an authenticated user/password to call the API. I just want to make sure that the only calls that the API accepts are those from the Angular app (and rejects direct calls from people using some sort of REST client)

How can I ensure that only my Angular application can call my Nest JS API?

Comment: CORS? in your main your ts `app.enableCors({origins: ['https://myApp.com']})`

Comment: Thanks for your response! Pardon my ignorance, but is this secure enough? Is there any way for people to spoof their origin? Thanks!

Comment: There are ways, but there is no 'client' security that can't be bypassed, by definition. But your spoofing concern does not apply to SSL afaik, so if you're communicating SSL to SSL only and not allowing any traffic over http, you'll also be checking certificates which you could manually check on top of what they already do. Why are you so worried about people using tools to access your API? Won't they be able to access your api anyway via your website? they could just open the console and make http callls right then and there, all legit.